What kind of lock is set on table when I run Update on that table within a transaction?
Let's imagine I have the following transaction:
BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE @id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID()
UPDATE A
WHERE A.id = @id

What kind of lock will be hold on the table A until I commit transaction?
Is it X-lock or S-lock or some other kind of lock?

Why don't you try it and see? What's reported in sys.dm_tran_locks while the transaction is in progress?

If id is the primary key, I expect an exclusive row lock (X) to be held until the transaction is committed.

I'm guessing no locks, because your statement will fail to compile

@AlwaysLearning I tried - several different locks were added in sys.dm_tran_locks
So I don't know which of them corresponds to my table

It depends of the table structure... If ID column is a PRIMARY KEY and the primary key have no other column, the lock will be a "row" lock :
if the PK is clustered, by a "logical" row lock
If the PK is nonclustered, by a "physical" row lock
In an UPDATE, the lock type is always a UPDATE lock, with begin by a shared to be an exclusive when the row is found. The first shared part of this lock forbid to add new shared locks... so that the shared lock can be transform in an exclusive one, when all other process have ends....
And the duration of the lock is only the time of the update plus the freeling of the shared concurrency locks in pessimistic locking...

U lock is compatible with S but incompatible with U.  The intent is to prevent two UPDATES from both finding the same row to update, and then both trying to get an X lock on the found row. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver16#lock_compatibility
